# UINavigationBar appearance with RECurtainViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm using an [RECurtainViewController](https://github.com/romaonthego/RECurtainViewController) to transition in a new view controller. In my app delegate I set my navigation bar appearance:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: @{
                                UITextAttributeTextColor: [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:255.0/255.0 blue:255.0/255.0 alpha:1.0],
                          UITextAttributeTextShadowColor: [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.8],
                         UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset: [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0.0f, 1.0f)],
                                     UITextAttributeFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:20.0f]
     }];
```

The root view controller with the navigation bar displays correctly. However, when I bring in a new view controller using:

```
DemoViewController *test = [[DemoViewController alloc] init];
[self curtainRevealViewController:test
                  transitionStyle:RECurtainTransitionHorizontal];
```

The UINavigationBar appearance is set back to its default. Any ideas how to make the custom appearance persist?

**EDIT:**

I noticed I'm also getting this Warning in the console when the DemoViewController is displayed:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <DemoViewController: 0x1ddaae70> on <ViewController: 0x1e892040> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

However, it still displays the view controller.

Comment: Is test wrapped inside a navigation controller? In the above code it looks like added directly.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. It's just added directly. Does it need to be in a navigation controller for UINavigationBar appearance to work?

Comment: I was wondering how is it displaying a navigationbar since you are directly adding it. Ideally it should be inside a navigation controller to get a navigation bar shown there.

Comment: I'm just adding a UINavigationBar to my view controller nibs. It works for the root view controller (the navigationbar appearance). It's the transition that messes it up and I can't figure out where things go wrong.

Comment: Try to create a `UINavitaionController` with `test` as its `rootViewController`. And then pass this `navigationController` object to `curtainRevealViewController` method and check. Do not add separate navigation bar.

Comment: Just tried that out - same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this by going into the viewDidLoad method in DemoViewController and assigning the attributes to the actual navBar instance:

```
[self.navBar setTitleTextAttributes: @{
                                UITextAttributeTextColor: [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:255.0/255.0 blue:255.0/255.0 alpha:1.0],
                          UITextAttributeTextShadowColor: [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.8],
                         UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset: [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0.0f, 1.0f)],
                                     UITextAttributeFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:20.0f]
     }];
```

Not sure why I have to do this, but it appears to work.